# Is it possible create current by spinning a charged sphere?

Tags: electricity, electric-current

If we have a sphere which has $σ$ surface charge density and rotate it in axis z will this create current ? Is it possible without any potential difference ?

Comment: 8.02 by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Let's assume that the charge density is fixed relative to the surface of a sphere of radius $R$, then spinning the sphere with angular velocity $\vec\omega = \omega \hat{z}$ would create a surface charge density $\vec K$ given by
$$
  \vec K(\theta, \phi) = \omega R\sin\theta\sigma(\theta, \phi)\hat\phi(\theta, \phi)
$$
where $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the polar and azimuthal spherical coordinates.

Comment: can we deduce the total charge of the sphere then?

Comment: The total charge on the sphere is still just $\int \sigma dA$ even though the sphere is spinning; the motion does not change the amount of charge on the sphere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the total current. Is it possible to find that?

Comment: By that do you mean the total charge per unit time passing through an arc on the sphere consisting of the portion of a great circle between $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = \pi$?  If so, then yes, you would simply compute the integral $\int_0^\pi d\theta \,R \vec K\cdot\hat\phi$.

Comment: So im still don't understand something.  You say that the spinning sphere creates a surface charge density $K$ but the total surface charge density remains the same. So what makes these charges move ? The air resistance while the sphere is spinning?

Comment: The spinning sphere constitutes a surface *current* density.  I'm assuming in my response that the charges are fixed relative to the sphere so that the surface charge density relative to the sphere remains the same (imagine somehow "gluing" the charges to an insulator), and I'm assuming that there is some external agent, like a person, who gets the sphere spinning.

Comment: @joshphysics: In a real conductor, are the charges fixed relative to the surface of the sphere?  Would nothing happen if you spun a superconductor?

Comment: @endolith In a conductor, charges are not fixed relative to the surface of the sphere.  Charges are, in fact, free to flow throughout the entire conductor.  You would need some sort of insulator to "glue" the charges in place.  I'm not sure what would happen if you were to spin a superconductor.  Perhaps you could ask that as a new Physics.SE question.